# Bijective comorphism of a polynomial map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, morphism

Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a polynomial map, between algebraic groups $G,H$ (ie defined by polynomial equations), such that the comorpism $f^*:K(H)\rightarrow K(G),\ g\mapsto g\circ f$ is bijective.

> > Is $f$ bijective and $f^{-1}$ a polynomial map?

If $f$ is an isomorphism of algebraic groups, then it is straightforeward that $f^*$ is bijective, but what about the converse?

This seems to follow from Tauvel and Yu's Lie Algebra and Algebraic groups 11.4.4, but I don't understand the proof. On the other hand I see that $f^*$ surjective implies $f$ injective, that $f^*$ injective implies $f$ dominant hence surjective, so $f$ is bijective.

Comment: I think this should follow from Zariski's main theorem.

Comment: @Callus, I think you are right, following an argument on MO. I am wondering if there is a shortcut using the assumption on $f^*$, which seems pretty strong.